# Matrix of a linear transformation in an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

> Let $B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^n$ and $T:R^n \to R^n$ be a linear transformation. Let $A=(a_{ij})$ a representing matrix of the transformation $T$ by basis $B$ (I am sorry if this is not the correct term of this matrix "representing matrix" I tried translating but could not find the correct term.) Prove that the element $a_{ij}$ is equal to $T(v_j)\cdot v_i$.

My try:

we know that the columns of the matrix are coordinate vectors of $T(v_j)$ so the coloumn $j$ of A is the coordinate $j$ vector of $T(v_j)$ and the row $i$ of A is the row $i$ of $T(v_j)$

we also know that if we have an Orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$ and let $a,b \in \Bbb R^n$ be any vectors in that space so we can represent $a$ as a linear combination of $B$ this way:

$a=\sum_{i=1}^n (a \cdot u_i)\cdot u_i$ so we can do that same in our case $T(v_j)=\sum_{b=1}^n (T(v_j) \cdot v_b)\cdot v_b$ and since it is an Orthonormal basis  we get that $T(v_j) \cdot v_b=1$ and I got stuck here

According to the textbook (they do not show the full solution and not the first parts) after this part : $T(v_j)=\sum_{b=1}^n (T(v_j) \cdot v_b)\cdot v_b$ it says that the Coefficient of vector $v_b$ is the coordinate $b$ of $T(v_j)$ and according to this we get that element $a_{ij}$ is equal to $T(v_j)\cdot v_i$

I did not understand the textbooks explanation can anyone help me understand and tell me if my way is correct? or if there is another way to suggest?

I am sorry for the English translations I wasn't able to find a translation for everything

Comment: I've seen it said like this: $A$ the matrix of the transformation $T$ relative to the basis $B$ (or in the basis $B$; or with respect to the basis $B$).

Comment: The standard notation for inner product is $\langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle$ . Most authors use this and not the parantheses $(\cdot,\cdot)$.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron appreciate all the great help and the explanation (also in the comment below) , in my textbook we dont use any notation probably because we get a small taste of that topic thank you again and happy I learned that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $$T(v_{j})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}v_{i}$$. by definition of the matrix of $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$.

So $$\langle T(v_{j}),v_{k}\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}v_{i},v_{k}\right\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}\langle v_{i},v_{k}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}\delta_{ik}=a_{kj}$$.
Where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta. such that $\delta_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1\,,i=j\\0\,,i\neq j\end{cases}$.
Basically all other terms become $0$ by Orthogonality and only $\langle v_k,v_k\rangle$ survives and equals $1$.

Thus the $kj$-th entry of the matrix is given by $\langle T(v_{j}),v_{k}\rangle$.

Comment: very interesting way , can you please explain a bit more about what made you use Kronecker delta? I saw this in the textbook but could not figure how it can be used in anyway

Comment: Ans by $\langle T(v_{j}),v_{k}\rangle$ you mean the orthonormal product right?

Comment: Kronecker delta is just a short hand for saying that $<v_{i},v_{j}>=0$ if $i \neq j$ and $1$ if $i=j$.  Which is just the definition of orthonormality. Many people just use the Kronecker delta so as to not write out the whole sentence. What's happening is that only one term of the summation survives. And $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ means the inner product wrt which you are defining the notion of orthogonality. There is nothing call the "orthogonal product" or the "orthonormal product". A pair of vectors which is orthonormal wrt some inner product might not be even orthogonal wrt another

Answer (score 1):

We have the following :
$T(e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n)=(e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n)A$. $A=(a_{ij})$
so we obtain $T(e_j)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij} e_i $. Computing
inner product $\langle {T(e_j),e_i} \rangle$  and by linrearity and orthogonality we verify $a_{ij}=\langle {T(e_j),e_i} \rangle$